# mod_rewrite adds trailing slash - how to stop this behavior?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I'm trying to figure out how to stop this behavior. mod_rewrite adds slash after the domain name when removing "www" prefix.

The rules that I'm currently using to convert all http traffic to https and to remove www prefix:

```
*:80 Vhost:
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect all HTTP calls to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

*:443 Vhost:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.DOMAIN.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://DOMAIN.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

So if I'm going to "https://www.DOMAIN.com" it normally adds "/#!/" but now it also adds another slash so it's giving me 301 to "https://DOMAIN.com//#!/"

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your last rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://DOMAIN.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It worked! I'm not sure if people other than me can see it, but you answered me in less than a minute :) Thanks!

Comment: @Yoav This is because he can use his great magic tooth picker. Take a look at his avatar...